# MultipleObjectsReturned get() returned more than one KVStore

Tags: python, django, solr, thumbnails, sorl-thumbnail

I'm using django sorl-thumbnail for managing thumbnails and I have following error

MultipleObjectsReturned at 'some-url'
get() returned more than one KVStore -- it returned 2!

Do you know how to handle this problem?

Comment: You have more than one objects with same lookup field value. You have to use 'get' on 'pk' or 'unique field'. Using filter instead of get will work for your case but will return a query-set.

Comment: But this is not the case, because this error occur in templates when using {% thubmnail %} tag and I dont have access to underlying solr-thumbnail function where object is returned

Comment: Can you please share the template code here. and refer this link https://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/template.html#thumbnail as well

Comment: Here is the link https://pastebin.com/NyctvZeD